# 2 missing dependencies when including a jar with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I'm working on a web-app, and in order to minimise the number of dependencies in it's **pom.xml**, I have created a jar with all the dependencies needed.

but when adding this jar dependency on my web project, it seems that 2 existing dependencies on the jar are not being included in my web-app.

**pom.xml of my web app :**

```
<!-- rest-easy-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>rest-easy-api</groupId> 
    <artifactId>rest-easy-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**The 2 missing dependencies (which are included in my jar) :**

```
<!-- EclipseLink's JPA capabilities for relational databases. -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope> 

    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>commonj.sdo</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency> 

<!-- JPA 2.1 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

it's like the local repository is not updated.. I did clean both projects, removed them - re-import them. It still doesn't work..

Do you guys have any idea about what could be the reason of this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

That tells maven that the dependency will be provided by the runtime environment, so it will not be pulled into this build but only used at compile time.

Comment: Thank you, it works.. I guess I should read about the scope tag :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the provided scope, just for reimporting them into your local repo?